# (Existing) column name undefined error in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of two columns: 'FrameNo' and 'AGL'. I am trying to filter the dataframe rows by a specific value greater than a particular number in column 'AGL'. However, when I try to do this, I get an error that column 'AGL' is undefined. It's not, though.

Here's the code I'm using to create my dataframe and then filter by column 'AGL' values, followed by the error:

```
#combine lists into single two-column df
dfA = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(resultA, result)), 
               columns =['FrameNo','AGL']) 


dfA(dfA[AGL]>100.0)

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-1c478a8f034f> in <module>
----> 1 dfA(dfA[AGL]>100.0)

NameError: name 'AGL' is not defined
```

If I change the last line of my code to include quotes around the column name, I get a different error as follows:

```
dfA(dfA['AGL']>100.0)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

I'm also attaching an image of the first five rows of my dfA. [Image of first five rows of dfA.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ70x.png)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: your column AGL is not numeric, you cannot compare float and str. You need to convert your column to float `dfA['AGL'] = dfA['AGL'].astype('float')` and than if you want to filter your dataframe you need to write `dfA[dfA['AGL']>100.0]`

Comment: @DmitriyK.Thanks so much! That fixed the issue!